# black box function in CVXPY

Tags: python, cvxpy, cvxopt

Suppose I have a function `f(x)` which I know to be convex on the domain I am interested in (for example, `sin(x)` on `[0, Pi]`, but it may be some black box user-defined function). Is there any way to tell this to `CVXPY`?

Comment: No there is not. You need to use functions for which either you or cvxpy knows a conic representation.